# Are there any good podcasts for ASP.NET MVC architecture and design patterns?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, architecture, podcast

I'm looking for a few good podcasts for MVC3 and related architecture and also best practice and design patterns?

I have found loads that talk about new features and releases of packages but nothing that supports enterprise architecture and good practice.

Any recommendations for active podcasts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=257

http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=606

Comment: Any others I have been struggling to find many other great ones?

Answer (score 1):

This website has series of Podecasts about Asp.net MVC
[developerfusion.com](http://www.developerfusion.com/t/aspnet-mvc/media/#p/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Gotta throw in two more recent ASP.NET podcasts that are not on here, but regularly bring up the topic of MVC or related technologies.

[Away From The Keyboard](http://awayfromthekeyboard.com/)

and the second one I have is not specifically on the MVC architecture, but again it's in the ASP.NET genre and is about Source Control.

[Radio TFS](http://radiotfs.com/)

Answer (score -3):

See [Nido Framework](https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/), Nido is a code framework (a common project) written on .NET framework 4.0, Entity framework 6.0 and few other additional libraries to encourage you (we developers) to develop our systems adhering to good architectural disciplines.

https://nidoframework.codeplex.com/